# AngularJS views broken after oauth redirect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth, firebase, single-page-application

I'm developing an AngularJS + Firebase app, and I've gotten to a point where I added a second page and an ng-view in the index. I'm using the `$firebaseAuth` service for facebook/google login.

The problem is, upon logging in, the angular routing is broken due to `$firebaseAuth` redirecting to the site's url minus a slash at the end, which Angular is apparently dependent upon. (Using the `$authWithOAuthPopUp()` method)

for instance,
`https//app.firebaseapp.com/#/` would turn into `https://app.firebaseapp.com/#`

I have to refresh to get the `/` at the end back.

Is this a common problem, and is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I think this should be done on the server side with a rewrite rule.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by adding `$location.path('/')` to my `$onAuth()` function

Comment: But if anyone has a more elegant solution, feel free to answer.

Comment: I'm not sure how anyone could come to that conclusion, or a more elegant one, without seeing enough code to reproduce the problem. You haven't included any of the necessary code to make this question, or answer, meaningful to anyone else.